# Route function appears to not be detected

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I'm using a MVC pattern, structuring everything in that style.
*Server.js* call a *routes.js* file which is a list of all possible routes. From there I want to call the controller functions to respond to that request.

I am getting getting a 404 error when trying to use a function from the user controller.

> Server started on port 3000
>
> MongoDB Connected...
>
> GET /signUp 404 28.578 ms - 37

**Server.js**

```
//expose
module.exports = app;


// Bootstrap models //
fs.readdirSync(models)
  .filter(file => ~file.search(/^[^.].*\.js$/))
  .forEach(file => require(join(models, file)));


// Bootstrap routes //
require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./config/express')(app, passport);
app.use('/', routes);
```

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router(); 

// Controllers //
const Users = require('../../app/controllers/users');

// Other routes //
const index = require('./landing');

//Access to routes
router.use('/', index);

// USER ROUTES //
router.post('/signUp', Users.signUp);

module.exports = router;
```

**users.js**

```
// @route    POST signUp
// @desc     SignUp/ Register user
// @access   Public
const signUp = async (req, res) => {
    [
        //some checks
    ];
    try{ //some code
    } catch(err) {
       //error handling
    }
```

It seem that it's due to the controller function, I've tried changing the way I declare the route, but this is the way that makes the most sense to me.
I've started from this ["boilerplate"](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo), but I don't get the way the routing works. So I changed it to be this way.

What am I doing wrong?

### **EDIT**

As pointed out by [@Gavin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2244284/gavin)Gavin in the comments, the 404 error I'm getting does not match the router.post bit.
So I've went and tried with Postman, It seems to detected the route since I get a 500 server error now. However, in the browser I'm still getting a 404 request.

> POST /signUp 500 60.652 ms - 73  //when I try with postman
>
> GET /signUp 404 36.685 ms - 37 //when I refresh the browser

Comment: `GET /signUp 404 28.578 ms - 37` looks like a GET request but `router.post('/signUp', Users.signUp);` looks like it's exposing a POST route. Try changing request to POST or changing router.post to router.get (or .all if it exists and is appropriate to do so).

Comment: I didn't even notice that at first! I've now tried it with postman, and get a 500 server error, but when I refresh the browser, I still get a 404 error. Any clue as to what might be happening? @Gavin

Comment: 500 is the generic 'something went wrong' so that could be anything. Try adding an error handler to echo some information out when it occurs (if it isn't already!): http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#error-handling

Comment: @Gavin after some investigation, I'v figured out, that the 500 internal error is due to check I have to try and find if a User with those given arguments already exists, since I had none in the database to try and compare, it gave an error. So that's fixed.